# Young's Modulus of a non linear, elastic material

Tags: education

is it possible to define Young's modulus of an elastic, non linear material?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can and it is called the incremental Young's modulus.
A point of interest on the stress against strain graph is chosen and the gradient of the graph at that point is the incremental Young's modulus.
The incremental Young's modulus can then be used to find how the strain changes for small changes of stress.

This is similar to the use of incremental / dynamic / small signal resistance in electronics when a circuit element has a non-linear current-voltage characteristic.

Comment: Hi @Farcher, could you reccomend me a book to examine in depth the argument please?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I hope you will not think me rude if I give you a short answer of "No, I cannot recommend a book".  I would suggest that you start off the googling **incremental Young's modulus** or any other modulus or something similar to see what you get.  It is highly likely that some of the links that you go to have books as reference or are pdf copies of books.  Having just done this I note that a lot of the reference are medical.

Answer (score 2):

You can model nonlinear modulus by using the secant modulus. which is the slope of the straight line  on a stress strain diagram connecting the beginning and ending strain